React state change on button click
My calling component,
export const CallingComponent = () => {
  const [getApiData, setApiData] = //initial data binding from api

  return (
    <CustomComponent
      defaultValue={getApiData()}
      onChange={(value: { toString: () => any }) => setApiData(value.toString())
      }
    />
  );

Component which is trying to pass state string to calling component on "Update" button click but its not passing editor content to setApiData state in calling code,
interface CustomComponentProp {
  onChange?: (value: string) => void;
  defaultValue?: string;
}

export const CustomComponent = ({defaultValue,onChange}: CustomComponentProp) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const editorRef = useRef([] as any);
  const [data, setData] = useState(defaultValue);
  const [initialDefault, setInitialDefault] = useState(defaultValue);

  if (initialDefault != defaultValue) {
    setInitialDefault(defaultValue);
    setData(defaultValue);
  }

  const handleEditorDidMount = (editor: any) => {
    editorRef.current = editor;
    editor.focus();
  };

  function handleRemove() {
    setData("");
    setValue("");
  }

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      const content = editorRef.current.getValue();
      setData(content);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Settings>
      <SettingsSection>
        <Editor
          theme="vs-light"
          language="scss"
          value={data}
          onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
          onChange={(value) => setValue(value as string)}
        />
          <Button variant="outline" onPress={handleUpdate}>
            Update
          </Button>
          <Button variant="outline" onPress={handleRemove}>
            Remove
          </Button>
      </SettingsSection>
    </Settings>
  );
};

What I am looking to update setApiData state when Update button is clicked.

Have you tried using onChange inside the handleUpdate()
    if (editorRef.current) {
      const content = editorRef.current.getValue();
      setData(content);
      if (onChange) onChange(content); // Call the onChange with the updated content
    }
  };

When the "Update" button is clicked, the content of the editor is fetched using editorRef.current.getValue() and stored in data. If the onChange prop is provided, it should be called with the new content. Try this and let me know if it works.

Maybe i missed something from your question but it should be pretty straightforward.
Assuming you are using MUI, you can use onClick:
<Button variant="outline" onClick={handleUpdate}>
        Update
</Button>

Docs for MUI Button:
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/
Docs for HTML button:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

onclick says : Type '{ children: string; variant: "outline"; onclick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps'.
Property 'onclick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps'

Im assuming Button is a MUI Button.
If not, you should check what library are you importing that Button from and check its docs.

Also, it should be onClick (with a C uppercase), i made a mistake when writing the answer. See the edit please.

Button event works fine, it can set new state through setData(content);

Yeah, sorry mate. It seems that im misunderstanding the question then.
